# C++ reflection how it is achieved

Tags: c++, reflection, template-meta-programming

I know that C++ does not support reflection, but I went through paper [Reflection support by means of template meta-programming](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.20.8519&rep=rep1&type=pdf) , But did not understand how this is achieved. Would anybody have more details or examples on how this can be achived in C++ using template meta-programming?

Comment: Looks horrendously complex, for relatively little reward. Fairly minimal sorts of runtime reflection too. Did you have a specific problem in mind that required this sort of poor-man's reflection, or were you interested in C++ reflection in general?

Comment: Trying to fit square pegs into round holes is always difficult.

Comment: Did you read the paper? Certainly it has the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Rewriting the whole paper in simpler language would be quite a lot of work. Do you have any more specific questions about the parts you don't understand?

Comment: the paper link is broken now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example of a struct that tests at compile time if a Type of type Obj has a public data member of type Type that is named "foo". It uses C++11-features. While it can be done using C++03-features, I consider this approach superior.

First, we check if Obj is a class using std::is_class. If it is not a class, it cannot have data members so the test returns false. This is achieved with the partial template specialization below.

We will use SFINAE to detect if the object contains the data member. We declare the struct helper that has the template parameter of type "pointer to data member of type Type of the class Obj". Then we declare two overloaded versions of the static function test: The first, which rsturns a type indicating a failed test accepts any parameter via the ellipsis. Note that the ellipsis has the lowest precendence in overload resolution. The second, which returns a type indicating success, accepts a pointer to the helper struct with template
parameter &U::foo. Now we check what a call to test with U bound to Obj returns if called with a nullptr and typedef that to testresult. The compiler tries the second version of test first since the ellipsis is tried last. If helper<&Obj::foo> is a legal type which is only true if Obj has a public data member of type Type then this overload is chosen and
testresult will be std::true_type. If this is not a legal type the overload is excluded from the list of possible candidates (SFINAE) so the remaining version of test which accepts any parameter type will be chosen and testresult will be std::false_type. Finally, the static member value of testresult is assigned to our static member value which indicates whether our test was successful or not.

One downside of that technique is that you need to know the name of the data member you are testing explicitly ("foo" in my example) so to do that for different names you would have to write a macro.

You can write similar tests to test if a type has a static data member with a certain name and type, if it has an inner type or typedef with a certain name, if it has a member function with a certain name that can be called with given parameter types and so on but that exceeds the scope of my time right now.

```
template <typename Obj, typename Type, bool b = std::is_class<Obj>::value>
struct has_public_member_foo
{
  template <typename Type Obj::*> 
  struct helper;

  template <typename U>
  static std::false_type test(...);

  template <typename U>
  static std::true_type test(helper<&U::foo> *);

  typedef decltype(test<Obj>(nullptr)) testresult;

  static const bool value = testresult::value;
};

template <typename Obj, typename Type>
struct has_public_member_foo<Obj, Type, false> : std::false_type { };

struct Foo
{
  double foo;
};

struct Bar
{
  int bar;
};


void stackoverflow() 
{
  static_assert(has_public_member_foo<Foo, double>::value == true, "oops");
  static_assert(has_public_member_foo<Foo, int>::value == false, "oops");
  static_assert(has_public_member_foo<Bar, int>::value == false, "oops");
  static_assert(has_public_member_foo<double, int>::value == false, "oops");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to query certain characteristics of a type at compile time.
The simplest case is probably the built-in `sizeof` operator. As MadScientist
posted, you can also probe for specific members.

Within frameworks that use generic programming or template metaprogramming
there are typically contracts on the synopsis of classes (formalized as
*Concepts*).

The STL for instance uses a member typedef `result_type` for function objects. 
`boost:result_of` (that later became `std::result_of`) extended this contract
to allow a nested class template in order to compute the result type of a 
function object whose parameters were generic (in other words - having an 
overloaded or template `operator()`). Then `boost:result_of` would perform compile
time reflection to allow client code to determine the result type of a function
pointer, STL function object or "templated function object" uniformly allowing
to write more generic code that will "just work" in either case. Sidenote: C++11
can do better in this particular case - I used it as the example because it is
both nontrivial enough and based on widespread components.

Further it is possible to use client code that will emit a data structure that
contains meta information deduced at compile time (or even passed-in by client
code) when registering a certain type. The framework code could e.g. use the 
`typeid` operator to obtain a runtime representation of the type and generate
call stubs for a specific constructor, the destructor and a set of member 
functions (some might be optional) and store this information in a `std::map`
keyed by `std::type_index` (or a hand-written wrapper around `std::type_info`
for older versions of the language). At a later point in the program this
information can be found given (a runtime representation of) some object's type
in order to run an algorithm that e.g. creates more instances of the same type
where some have temporary lifetime, run some operations and tidy up.

Combining both techniques is very powerful, because code that is to be run
at high complexity can be generated at compile time using aggressive inlining
for possibly many variations generated from templates on the fly, interfacing
with less time-critical parts by similar means at program run time.